# Is autosave function possible in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm working on my own project where user able to log in and they can play games from their profile and i also have read only textbox where the scores shows up in the profile and i am wondering is it possible for me to auto save that score in the database without the user clicking save.

so far i have completed all this but i am just wondering is auto save possible in php or do i have to use completely different language.

I am using php and sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a php page that will edit the table. scorekeeper.php?userid="[USERID]"&userscore=[USERSCORE]

and call that php by using Ajax Jquery every interval that you want with the userid and userscore variables.

Comment: This way everyone can manually enter any score and any ID they want.

Comment: you can encrypt userid and userscore with an encrypted javascript or php and decrypt it on the scorekeeper.php then run the query

Comment: one step at a time. First I will create the auto save function then i will implement the security btw have you guys got any online resource that may help me out, I never used AJAX or Jquery.